# How do I give a TextView a Scrollbar without an XML layout?

Tags: android, scrollbar

I'm making a `TextView` scrollable using :
`textView.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()`

But it's not showing a Scrollbar. How can I add one, and style it ?

In addition to this, how can I make the scroll keep going when the user does a quick swipe ? Usually when you make a big movement, the scroll keeps going for a while but that's not the case here.

Thanks.